# How to get second best predicted value by Python code using Random Forest Technique?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have tried to learn a machine learning with Random Forest classifier. Now I can predict best crop using following python code. Screenshot is displayed below.
[screenshot of best crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mckdF.jpg)

Now I want to know how to get the second best recommended crop using this code. What should I do? My existing Code is like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import tree
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

df = pd.read_csv('crops.csv')

df.head()

df.tail()

#print(df.head())

df.describe()
#print(df.describe())

df['Crop_Label'].unique()

#list_crop= df['Crop_Label'].unique()


#print(list_crop)

#b = np.array('Maniocs')
#c = np.setdiff1d(list_crop,b)
#print(c)

s = df.corr()
#print(s)

sns.heatmap(s,annot = True)

features = df[['Avg_Temp','Avg_Rainfall','Avg_Humidity','Extent','Production']]
target = df['Crop_Label']
print(target)

# Initialzing empty lists to append all model's name and corresponding name
acc = []
model = []

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(features,target,test_size= 0.2,random_state = 2)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=29, criterion = 'entropy',random_state=0)
RF.fit(X_train,y_train)
predicted = RF.predict(X_test)
x = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,predicted)
acc.append(x)
model.append('Random Forest')
#print("Random Forest Accuracy is ",x * 100)
#print(classification_report(y_test,predicted))

score = cross_val_score(RF,features,target,cv = 2)

score

data = np.array([[29,150, 80, 24006, 100]])
prediction = RF.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

My sample CSV file is here. Link is :-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IcIwZQI08sQxxTNOV0MPP30llkjvqtD2/view?usp=sharing

Please give me any idea to get the second best crop using prediction using above code. Thank You.